# Is $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x \cdot y=1\}$ a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Meanwhile it is well know that
$$M:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x \cdot y=0\}$$
not a submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$ is. The next question is now, is for example
$$L:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x \cdot y=1\}$$
Is now $L$ a submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Yes, it is a submanifold..

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Draw pictures of $M$ and $L$, and compare.

Comment: Drawing the set, I should be 2 graphs.. But how can I show it more “strictly”?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Submersion theorem* to show this. If you don't want to use this theorem, then you must explicitly construct a smooth atlas of this submanifold which should be easy.

Comment: Oh thank you! We could define for example the function $f(x,y):=xy-1$ and show that $0$ is a regular value of $f$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that :)

Comment: Or, if you note that this is a graph of a smooth function, you can give a (global) chart.